# Rigid Bodies - objects exploding and clipping

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

[image]

Well, the title just explains my problem. I have been searching online but cant find any solution for me to understand.
At first I started with real lego size blocks and the I read rigid boides arent to friendly with small object, so I scaled them but problem persist.
I tried icnreasing steps per second, playing and tweaking around but nothing cool came out of it :(

The animation Im aming for is that the moving wall just "clears" the legos from their original position in a natural and organic movement
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See the weight of all objects and make sure none is intersecting with each other.
And yes, change the collision identifier from convex hull to mesh.

Comment: I don't think that changing the collision model is the right thing to do here. 
There are only two areas where the convex hull would be any different from the mesh - the hollow bottom of the bricks and the space next to the studs, which is not worth the decrease in performance.